# Function defined as determinant of polynomial matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, polynomials, induction, determinant

I have the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f_n(t) = \det\left(\begin{array}{ccc}p_0(t)&\dots&p_n(t)\\
p'_0(t)&\dots&p'_n(t)\\
p''_0(t)&\dots&p''_n(t)\\
\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
p^n_0(t)&\dots&p^n_n(t)\end{array}\right)
\end{equation*}
Where $p_i(t)$ are polynomials of degree $\leq n$ and $p^k_i(t)$ is the $k$-th derivative.

I'm trying to show that $f(t) = f(0), \forall t$. Now, $f(0)$, as far as I understand, works out to be the determinant of the coefficient matrix multiplied by some constant.

I decided to try this by induction, but I'm stuck on the inductive step. This is what I have so far:

We prove the general case, for $n \geq 1$ via induction on $n$.
For our base case, let $n = 1$ and let $p_i(t) = a_{i1}t+a_{i0}$ for $i \in \{0,1\}$. We have
\begin{equation*}
f(t) = \det\left(\begin{array}{cc}a_{01}t+a_{00} & a_{11}t+a_{10}\\
a_{01}&a_{11}\end{array}\right)= (a_{01}t+a_{00})a_{11} - (a_{11}t+a_{10})a_{01} \\ = a_{01}a_{11} t-a_{01}
   a_{11}t-a_{01} a_{10}+a_{00}
   a_{11} = a_{00} a_{11}-a_{01} a_{10}.
\end{equation*}
Clearly, $f(t)$ does not depend on $t$, and so, $f(t) = f(0)$ for all $t$.

Now, we assume that the result holds for all $i < k$. We show that this implies that the result holds for $k$ as follows.
Let $p_i(t) = a_{ik}t^k+ \dots +a_{i0}$ for $i \in \{0,k\}$. We have
\begin{equation*}
f(t) = \det\left(\begin{array}{ccc}p_0(t)&\dots&p_k(t)\\
\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
p^k_0(t)&\dots&p^k_k(t)\end{array}\right)= \sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^{i}p_i(t)\det(M_{1,i+1}) = \sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^{i}p_i(t)f_{{k-1}_{1,i+1}}(0)
\end{equation*}
where $M_{m,n}$ is the minor matrix of the $m$-th row and $n$-th column and $f_{{k-1}_{1,i+1}}$ is $\det(M_{1,i+1})$ evaluated at $t = 0$. In our case, since $p_i(t)$ has degree at most $k$, $p'_i(t)$ has degree at most $k-1$, and so, for any $i$, $M_{1,i+1}$ is a matrix of the given form for $n = k-1$. By the induction hypothesis, for all $i$, $\det(M_{1,i+1})$ is a constant that does not depend on $t$.

I'm not really sure how to proceed from here, why does it follow that the resulting equation does not depend on $t$? I guess it has something to do with the fact that we're multiplying each polynomial by the determinant (times some constant) of the remaining polynomials' coefficients (except the constant coefficient, $a_{i0}$, which is lost in the first derivative).

I don't see any other links here that would allow me to proceed.

Comment: You say that the degree of $p_i$ is $\leq k$. Is it $k$, or $i$ ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I meant $n$, all the $p_i$ have the same degree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $f(t)=f(0)$ for all $t$ if and only if $f(t)$ is constant, if and only if $f'(t)=0$.

**Hint 2** By the product rule, the derivative of a determinant is the sum of the determinants obtained by derivating ONE row, and keeping the rest unchanged.

Comment: Excellent, thank you!!